How long does it take to join ros2-gbp release team?
I have had a ros2 package to release for quite a while. The procedure for releasing a ros2 package involves creating a release team to host the package on ros2-gbp. I had raised an issue for the same almost two weeks back but there has been no response. Is this usually how long it takes to create release team? Or has there been a change in procedure that I may not be aware about?
Alternatively, is it okay if I host the release package on my profile like I have for ROS1 releases?

There is more info in this thread on the ROS Discourse.
See also the remark by Katherine Scott:

You can also ping the infra team on Discord in the #infra-help channel.

